# Is there a way to make a custom field look more visually prominent in lightning layouts?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, custom-field

I have a custom field (checkbox) on the Account object, it's been placed in the details section which is towards the top of the page layout, but I would like to make it more prominently visible by either highlighting it or any other way if this is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with anything out of the box. You can really only control where the field shows up on the layout and whether it is required or not.

However, *depending on what you're trying to achieve* you could look to utilize a custom formula field which can display a different image depending on the value of the checkbox if you're looking to get across something important.

This [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327122&type=1&mode=1) goes over adding them, but it's really dependent on what you're trying to convey. An easy example to show the benefit of this is for a scenario where a checkbox may signify a "denied account". You could have the formula field display a big red X when checked or a green check mark when not selected.

[image]

That's one way to make the info more visually prominent within the standard layout (or list view). Steps below are taken from the linked knowledge article (for Lightning):

> 1. Create a public library to hold your image files. For steps, see
>      [Enable the Library Component](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_libraries_setup.htm&type=5),
> 2. Upload your image files to your new library. For steps, [see Add
>      Files to a Library](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_libraries_add_files.htm&type=5).
> 3. Create a custom field within the Object where you want the images to
>      display (formula field of type Text)
> 4. Obtain the URL to the image files uploaded in Step 2 (go to file, right click image in image preview and select "copy image address").
> 5. Example URLs: "/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/06846000002mPro"
> 6. In your new custom field, enter the image URL into your formula
>      field using the "IMAGE" function.
> 7. In the text area, enter your formula using the "IMAGE" function to
>      retrieve the image file you uploaded in Step 2.
> 8. Paste the image URL into the "image_url" section of the IMAGE
>      function. Don't include the Salesforce domain (ex. "/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0687000000dz7Ex")

Comment: I love your answer, I needed to exclusively thank you! @Kris Goncalves. also if you think my question is worth upvoting, I'll strongly appreciate it!

Comment: If you can't find the Libraries from setup, please follow the instructions on this link to enable it in your org: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gguoAAA